# diamond questionmark in unity www.text

Tags: c#, php, sql, mysqli, unity-game-engine

Im trying to get some text from my localhost with the following c# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class get_kings : MonoBehaviour {
public string url = "http://localhost/kings/get_kings.php";
public string firstname;
public Text countText;

IEnumerator Start() {


    // hämta hem data om kungarna
    WWW www = new WWW(url);

    // vänta på att datana laddas ner
    yield return www;

    // spara texten

    firstname =  www.text;

    Debug.Log (firstname);

    setCountText ();
}

void setCountText() {
    countText.text = firstname;
}
```

Problem being it displays the text but all my special chars like Å Ä Ö gets the dreaded black questionmark. No matter what collation/charset i run from my db.

```
<?php include "db_connect.php"?>
<?php

//get all data from db
$sql = "SELECT *FROM testar";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["name"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

No matter if i run utf-8 utf-16 or anything else I cannot get the special chars to be displayed correctly when running my unity application. Is there something i can do in unity to force the encoding?

/Emil

Comment: Try to give the php file proper html headers and meta tags like `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: Try [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) or [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

I made a workaround by using:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are outputting to a browser, set the charset for the html. [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp)

```
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

It's good to make sure that all your pieces are speaking in the same charset.

Comment: Hi, problem is im reading the first row that comes out in a c# script in unity3d thus giving me the <meta> tag, something i do not wish for :) The above workaround worked fine tough.